# convert json response to dynamic specific object in .net C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm working on .NET Core where I'm trying to masking some sensitive data like `emailid`, `password`, etc.. I want all my json response data keys or properties name should be in lowercase for that I'm using one of the feature of Newtonsoft e.g ContractResolver which helps us to customize property name.
But it seems, it only works with generic class type e.g

```
class customer
{
   public string firstName { get; set; } 
}
```

but it not working when we have json string e.g

```
{\n   \n    \"firstName\": \"Testbusiness\",\n    \"lastName\": \"business\",\n}
```

now i'm looking for how to convert json response to specific object type dynamically so that i can pass that object to contractResolver checkout below code.

```
public class LowerCaseResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
   protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        return propertyName.ToLower();
    }
}
```

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SerializationContractResolverExample.ContractResolver;
using System;

namespace SerializationContractResolverExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CustomerInfo customerInfo = new CustomerInfo()
            {
                FirstName = "Sukhpinder",
                LastName = "Singh",
                MobileNumbers = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>() {
                 "33443434343"
                }
            };

            var sestting = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new LowerCaseResolver()
            };

            // need to convert below response to dynamic generic type 
            string tem1 = "{\n    \"lmsUserId\": 10268,\n    \"landlordProfileId\": \"2ea81674-6ca6-478c-a9c6-fefbe9572f28\",\n    \"firstName\": \"Testbusiness\",\n    \"lastName\": \"business\",\n    \"email\": \"yesteluydi@vusra.com\",\n    \"createdBy\": 1551,\n    \"createdDate\": \"2022-05-05T17:05:10.37\",\n    \"user\": null,\n    \"linkedLLCs\": null,\n    \"ssn\": null,\n    \"accountTypeId\": 2,\n    \"completeLater\": false\n}";

            var responseLowerCase = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tem1, Formatting.Indented, sestting);  //Not working
            
            var responseLowerCase = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerInfo, Formatting.Indented, sestting); //Working Fine 

            Console.WriteLine(responseLowerCase);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"need to convert below response to dynamic generic type "_ - and where/how you are trying to do that?

Comment: _"but it not working when we have json string e.g"_ - why do you expect it to be working with string? string is a valid json primitive and serializer is not supposed to guess about it's contents. You need to deserialize the string one more time and serialize it with new contract.

Comment: You have to learn what is the difference between serialize and deserialize at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to convert tem1 to `Object` .

```
string tem1 = "{\n    \"lmsUserId\": 10268,\n    \"landlordProfileId\": \"2ea81674-6ca6-478c-a9c6-fefbe9572f28\",\n    \"firstName\": \"Testbusiness\",\n    \"lastName\": \"business\",\n    \"email\": \"yesteluydi@vusra.com\",\n    \"createdBy\": 1551,\n    \"createdDate\": \"2022-05-05T17:05:10.37\",\n    \"user\": null,\n    \"linkedLLCs\": null,\n    \"ssn\": null,\n    \"accountTypeId\": 2,\n    \"completeLater\": false\n}";
   var s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(tem1);
```

result:
[image]

Comment: I tried it with above code but still didn't work for me i want stogly type object like if the response is for customer list then object should be customer and if the response is employee then it should be employee object etc

Comment: I'm afraid not.You needs to use a parameter to tell which type you want to convert,it will not be converted to the type you want automatically.